# I want to block a certain url, what kind of condition do I have to write in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There's a critical security breach in Revolution Slider, a plugin for WordPress. It works by accessing a certain URL that let's download the config files eg.
 `www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=revslider_show_image&img=../wp-config.php`

I've been trying to make a rewrite condition so that url wouldn't be accessible anymore. This is what I have now in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=revslider_show_image&img=(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$ /?%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

but it doen't work, I'm not very familiar with rewrites, any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do in this rule: `RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$ /?%1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to protected file, you should forbid it (with `F` flag, equivalent to 403).
Also, you have an error in your condition's pattern.

Put this code in your htaccess **before** Wordpress' main rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=revslider_show_image&img=[^&]*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work okay. It's only a temporary fix until I get the plugins updated.

Answer (score 1):

Justin's answer will work and directly answers your "how do i" question, BUT...

This will prevent Rev Slider from working entirely, since you're forbidding the ajax call which is used to get and display an image.

I know you're looking for a quick fix until you get the plugin updated (which I did confirm myself today, patching to 4.6 works just fine), but be careful about HOW you're doing it. The best thing for you to do is update the plugin, not to implement this.